# Getting TLE in Codechef challenge

Tags: c++

https://www.codechef.com/problems/ADTRI
please tell me the reason why I am getting tle for the last subtask for this problem.
here is my code https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8614259

Comment: Please be more explicit, what your question is. Add a minimalized version of your code to the question and elaborate on what is wrong wih it.

Comment: question is: given  a number n,you have to find out if it can be a hypotenuse of a right angled triangle or not. A number can be represented as a sum of square of two numbers iff it is divisible by a prime number of the form 4k+1. that's what i am implementing in the code. My code is giving correct answers for all the other test cases except the last one which is giving tle. I want to know what's wrong in my code because loop is not terminating in the given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is nothing wrong in your code..but the time limit exceeded as
>   because for the last subtask your algo is running in O(sqrt(n)) time.
>   So overall it is running `(T*sqrt(n))` times. Now here `T=10^6` and `N=5*10^6`
>   `sqrt(n)~2*10^3`  there are almost `2*10^3*10^6` or `2*10^9` operations
>   which requires `> 1 sec` . That's why you are getting `TLE`..